# Determining if two polygons are overlapping in Google Maps?

Tags: google-maps, overlapping-features

I'm working with google maps and polygons, but I have to validate that polygons are not overlapping each other.

I have a function that returns TRUE when a point (lat, lng) is inside a polygon, but it's not enough to determine if every point of a polygon is inside another polygon.

Any suggestion?

Comment: Took me about 10 seconds to find https://github.com/tparkin/Google-Maps-Point-in-Polygon. Did you try anything?

Comment: He wrote "I have a function that returns TRUE when a point (lat, lng) is inside a polygon". I think it is a good trial but does not answer if the whole polygon is inside another.

Comment: I would add the [Javascript Topology Suite library](https://github.com/bjornharrtell/jsts) to your project and take advantage of its spatial operators for this sort of comparison. I provided an answer on a similar question showing [how to include the jsts library in a project and perform a dissolve/union on two polygon geometries](http://gis.stackexchange.com/a/100262/4968). You might find that helpful. If I have a chance I'll see if I can find or create an example that tests for intersection of two geometries--polygon, line, or point will not matter, they either intersect or they don't. :)

Comment: Have a look at the **intersect** method of the [LatLngBounds](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/coordinates#LatLngBounds) class

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**JSFiddle Example**

I've created [a JSFiddle demonstrating a solution to your problem](https://jsfiddle.net/xzovu9x6/2/) using the [JavaScript Topology Suite (JSTS)](https://github.com/bjornharrtell/jsts) (JSTS) library.

**Explaination**

There are two steps to this approach. The first step converts your Google geometries into [WellKnownText (WKT)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-known_text) geometry expressions, which is a widely supported format. The second step uses JSTS to perform a JSTS [`geometry.intersects()`](http://bjornharrtell.github.io/jsts/doc/api/jsts.geom.Geometry.html#intersects) comparison of two WKT geometries.

To really understand this you'll need to have a basic understanding of WKT. Because the polygon geometries in your Google Map are not widely supported format, I immediately convert them into WKT geometries so that we can work with them in JSTS.

To do this easily, I used [the Wicket library](https://github.com/arthur-e/Wicket). Of course you can always home-roll your own Google-Polygon-to-WKT method, [or you're welcome to use one I wrote once upon a time](http://cartometric.com/blog/2014/06/06/convert-google-maps-polygon-api-v3-to-well-known-text-wkt-geometry-expression/), or you can use some other solution you might find. Personally, these days I just use Wicket, which as you can see, is wicked-simple:

```
// Pass in two Google Polygon objects.
// It returns two WellKnownText (WKT) geometry expressions.
// 
function UseWicketToGoFromGooglePolysToWKT( poly1, poly2 )
{
    var wicket = new Wkt.Wkt();

    wicket.fromObject(poly1);
    var wkt1 = wicket.write();

    wicket.fromObject(poly2);
    var wkt2 = wicket.write();

    return [wkt1, wkt2];
}
```

Next is the meat and potatoes--using JSTS to take two WKT geometries and test whether or not they intersect. Once again, relying on the library, there is not much to it:

```
// Pass in two WKT geometry expressions.
// It performs a JSTS intersects() comparison.
// 
function UseJstsToTestForIntersection( wkt1, wkt2 )
{
    // Instantiate JSTS WKTReader and get two JSTS geometry objects
    var wktReader = new jsts.io.WKTReader();
    var geom1 = wktReader.read(wkt1);
    var geom2 = wktReader.read(wkt2);

    if (geom2.intersects(geom1)) {
      alert('intersection confirmed!');
    } else {
      alert('..no intersection.');
    }
}
```

**How I linked the libraries in the Fiddle**

The fiddle linked above, and the solution I demonstrated requires adding two 3rd party libraries to your project--JSTS, and Wicket. Getting the code from their respective Githubs and incorporating it into your project is a different exercise. But for the fiddle, I linked to those libraries by referencing them in [an existing JSTS example](http://bl.ocks.org/christophermanning/4450188) I found posted by [Christopher Manning](http://bl.ocks.org/christophermanning), as well as [Wicket's own demo page](http://arthur-e.github.io/Wicket/sandbox-gmaps3.html). Basically I opened the pages, selected "View Source", and plucked relevant references to the two libraries. These were exact library endpoints I used:

```
http://arthur-e.github.io/Wicket/wicket.js
http://arthur-e.github.io/Wicket/wicket-gmap3.js
http://bl.ocks.org/christophermanning/raw/4450188/javascript.util.min.js
http://bl.ocks.org/christophermanning/raw/4450188/jsts.min.js
```

Comment: Also FWIW, there is [some useful overlap in this thread over at SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26037104/how-to-calculate-intersection-area-in-google-maps-api-with-jsts-library).