# How to generate list of polygons that fall within radius circle using Google Maps API?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api

I have created a [Web app](http://www.machlis.com/elections/CongressionalDistricts/) using Google Fusion Tables, the Google Maps API and [Derek Eder's Searchable Maps Template](http://derekeder.com/searchable_map_template/) that allows someone to enter an address and distance, and then see which US Congressional Districts fall within the radius circle. A blind site visitor asked if it's possible to include a **text list of those polygons that intersect with the radius circle**. I thought that was a great idea and would like to help visually impaired users make use of the application.

Derek shows how to do a [text list of *points* within the circle](https://github.com/derekeder/FusionTable-Map-Template/wiki/List-search-results), but not intersecting *polygons*. Would anyone know how to modify this results list code to show intersecting polygons?

I was trying to play around with [this code](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/185619/determining-if-two-polygons-are-overlapping-in-google-maps), but unfortunately I'm not very proficient in JavaScript (I use R to prepare all the data).